# npx from command line does not find imports?

Tags: npx, ts-node

I'm trying to run a simple `hello.ts` script from command line. This works if the script has no dependencies:

```
npx ts-node hello.ts
```

But as soon as I start adding some dependencies...

```
import _ from 'lodash';
console.log('hello');
```

It fails:

> Cannot find module 'lodash' or its corresponding type declarations.

It keeps failing even if I install the dependencies **globally**. So how do I tell `npx` (or `ts-node` for that matter) to consider globally installed dependencies?

### Update

Using `Node 16.9.1` (upgraded via `Version Lens`). The error seems to have disappeared after uninstalling/reinstalling the imported libraries a few times.

Comment: Strange, I've just encountered this problem too. What node and npm version are you on?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `npm >=1.0`, you can use npm link  to create a local link to a package already installed globally. (Caveat: *The OS must support symlinks.*)

IE: `npm install -g lodash && npm link lodash`

However, this doesn't come without its problems.

> npm link is a development tool. It's awesome for managing packages on your local development box. But deploying with npm link is basically asking for problems, since it makes it super easy to update things without realizing it.

As an alternative, you can install the packages locally as well as globally.

For additional information, see:

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-link/

https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/

Comment: I installed the packages globally. It didn't help. Is there a need for a fully fledged `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `n` package by any chance? I used `n` to change from a newer version of node (16.2.0) to an older version of node (12.13.0), ran `npm i` and `npx` failed with a different error.

Using `n` to change back to 16.2.0 seems to have resolved the issue so I'm thinking perhaps it was an issue with `package-lock.json` or such

Comment: Node 16.9.1. See my update.